# How to underline and bold tooltip chart js

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have a question for a chart on my website:
I would like to put some text on bold and underline on the Tooltip like this picture.

ChartJs picture:
[image]

I find that it's possible to take : *tooltipTitleFontStyle: "bold"* or      *titleFontStyle : 'bold'* but none works.

Do you have a solution for me ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

I've converted string to bold unicode characters and passed them to tooltip inside `label` callback. I needed to make bold only part of label. In my case i needed only numbers 0123456789 ->  [these are unicode bold chars], so i created simple map or you can use library for conversion example: [conversion library i've found (not tested)](https://github.com/davidkonrad/toUnicodeVariant). You can make other text efects like this. I used this approach because standard tooltip in chartjs is sufficent for my task and I don't want to code external tooltip from scratch only because of bold text. Tested with ES6.

Here are some handy tools if you want to make your own map like in this example:

- [Bold text generator](https://lingojam.com/BoldTextGenerator)
- [Unicode text decoder](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/)
- [Text normalizer](https://onlineunicodetools.com/normalize-unicode-text)

```js
unicodeValueMap: {
            0: '\u{1D7EC}',
            1: '\u{1D7ED}',
            2: '\u{1D7EE}',
            3: '\u{1D7EF}',
            4: '\u{1D7F0}',
            5: '\u{1D7F1}',
            6: '\u{1D7F2}',
            7: '\u{1D7F3}',
            8: '\u{1D7F4}',
            9: '\u{1D7F5}'
        }
```

In label callback i've just replaced normal string characters with unicodes stored in my map object.

```js
var options = {
  callbacks: {
    label: (item) => {
      let boldValue = "";
      [...item.formattedValue].forEach((char) => {
        if (char in unicodeValueMap) {
          boldValue += unicodeValueMap[char];
        } else {
          boldValue += char;
        }
      });
      return `${item.dataset.label}: ${boldValue}`
    };
  }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result tooltip with partial bold]

Hope this help's somebody

Answer (score -2):

Hi you can build your own tooltip so that it returns wherever you want, i.e. a custom html

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips

For the bold font the option of titleFontStyle must be inside options.tooltips:

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
        titleFontStyle: 'bold',
      titleFontSize: 24
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

You can see a working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/fpjzvh4m/

Hope this helps.

P.D: I recommend that when asking this type of questions that you include some of your code.

Comment: Question was about "some text" not the whole text, therefore your answer is wrong. Also your link does not include presented code, nor any code making the change to tooltip.